# How does a JavaScript function store local variables after being called?

Tags: javascript, function, memoization

I came upon this simplified example of a memoization function in JavaScript. It's then used to memoize a function that adds 2 to whatever number is passed in. When I saw this, it didn't seem obvious that the `memoize` function would continue to store the `cache` variable after being ran since it's not a property of `memoize`, just (seemingly) an ordinary local variable. Shouldn't it be overridden whenever `memoize` is called via `plusTwo`? Where can I find out more about this behavior in JavaScript?

```
var memoize = function(function_) {
    var cache = {};

    return function() { // What does this function do?

        //makes a string out of the arguments of the function that was passed in
        var arg_str = JSON.stringify(arguments);

        /* 
        sets the cache value for the arguments to the value that was already calculated 
        (if available) or calculates the value for the passed in function on its
        */
        cache[arg_str] = cache[arg_str] || function_.apply(function_, arguments);

        console.log(cache);
        // returns the calculated (or cached) value
        return cache[arg_str];
    };
};

var plusTwo = memoize(function (x) {
    return x + 2;
});

module.exports = memoize, plusTwo;
```

Comment: You're looking for [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: `memoize` isn't being called by `plusTwo`, the function that `memoize` *returned* is what `plusTwo` is.

Comment: It's not overridden because it is outside the function that is being returned

Comment: @moghya Great, thank you.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Ah, I see. Thanks.